# How to orientate chart label with WPF DataVizualization?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-visualization

I have a column chart but, as you see in the screenshot, the labels are overlapping. I'd like to display them vertically or in oblique.

Here's the actual horrible result:

[image]

Here's the xaml I wrote:

```
    <dvc:Chart Margin="4">
        <dvc:ColumnSeries Title="Ticket count by department" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets, Converter={StaticResource GroupChartConverter}}"
                          IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Item1}"
                          DependentValueBinding="{Binding Item2}">
        </dvc:ColumnSeries>
    </dvc:Chart>
```

I found solution using template or code behind but they use so many lines of code for a not so clean result. I'm sure it's just a matter of one or two lines of code but Google is not so talkative about this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with using a template?

```
<dvc:Chart Margin="4">
    <dvc:ColumnSeries Title="Ticket count by department" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Tickets, Converter={StaticResource GroupChartConverter}}"
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Item1}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Item2}">
        <dvc:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
            <dvc:CategoryAxis
                Orientation="X">
                <dvc:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="dvc:AxisLabel">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="dvc:AxisLabel">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}">
                                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </dvc:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
            </dvc:CategoryAxis>
        </dvc:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
    </dvc:ColumnSeries>
</dvc:Chart>
```